# Aligning inside tabular environment, specific cell

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I'm trying to align a specific content of a single cell.
For example,

```
\begin{tabular}{|r|r|}
   \hline
   1 & 2 \\
   \hline
   right & to \_ the \_ left \\
   \hline
   1 & 2 \\
   \hline
\end{tabular}
```

Is it possible `to_the_left` to be aligned to the left, but to leave *all* others on the right? Is it even possible to align (cell contents) inside an already defined `tabular` environment?

Comment: Instead of posting code snippets, it is always best to compose a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that includes `\documentclass` and any packages, so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: Side note: if you use an extended tabular environment with paragraph-style columns (e.g. `\begin{tabularx}{15cm}{|p{3cm}|X|X|m{3cm}|}`), then you can use [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/485478). Unfortunately, this does not seem to work with simple `l`, `c` or `r` columns.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can use `\multicolumn{1}{l}{<content>}` for `to_the_left` to switch the cell alignment just for this cell. If you want to have a vertical line you need to use `l|` instead, otherwise the line is missing for this cell.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|r|r|}
   \hline
   111111 & 222222 \\
   \hline
   right & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{left} \\
   \hline
   1 & 2 \\
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: Yes, I already tried this solution, but it's a bit hack-ish, though. Is there more 'elegant' solution? If not, it would be nice to have better solution in upcoming LaTeX.

Comment: LaTeX3 won't be around for another while and I don't think it will handle that any better. Tables use TeX primitives to format the cells and you need some form of interface to control that. I don't think there is a simpler way than `\multicolumn`. You could define yourself a shorter macro for this, but that's all.

Comment: Is there a variant of this solution that does not depend on whether the cell is adjacent to a vertical line or not?

Answer (score 18):

There is a "solution" that avoids `\multicolumn{1}{l}{...}` but it's *really* a hack:

```
right & left\hfill\vadjust{} \\
```

The `\hfill` alone won't do, because LaTeX works hard to remove all space from the end part of a cell. Instead of `\vadjust{}` also `\penalty0` or `\nobreak` can be used.

A `\multicolumn{1}{l}{...}` is, probably, more visible and easier to change in case it's not needed any more.

Answer (score 5):

You have a natural way to set alignment for some cells with [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{
  colspec= {|r|r|},
  cell{2}{2} = {l},
}
\hline
   111111111111 & 222222222222 \\
\hline
   right & to-the-left \\
\hline
   111 & 222 \\
\hline
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]