# Change align of a single cell in tabular

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Aligning inside tabular environment, specific cell](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33486/aligning-inside-tabular-environment-specific-cell)

I have a simple table with a given align. I want to know if there is a way to specify a different align for a cell. For example, in the following table, how can I make Item 3 align right?

```
\begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{|l|r|}
        \hline
        Header1 & HeaderX \\ \hline
        Item1   & X1      \\ 
        Item2   & X2      \\ 
        Item3   & X3      \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Side note: if you use an extended tabular environment with paragraph-style columns (e.g. `\begin{tabularx}{15cm}{|p{3cm}|X|X|m{3cm}|}`), then you can use [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/485478). Unfortunately, this does not seem to work with simple `l`, `c` or `r` columns.

Answer (score 176, accepted):

Use `\multicolumn` -- it also works for single cells. Note that you have to specify any vertical rules also in the second argument of `\multicolumn`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{|l|r|}
        \hline
        Header1 & HeaderX \\ \hline
        Item1   & X1      \\ 
        Item2   & X2      \\ 
        \multicolumn{1}{|r|}{Item3}   & X3      \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You can use 'c' to justify centre. For example, `\begin{tabular}{|l|c|}`

Comment: The multicolumn method messes up the column width if it occurs in the first row.

Comment: Similar problem to @AFog, If it is the first row and not the rightmost column it is fine, but if it is the rightmost column - it would mess it up.