# Horizontally align a multirow cell in a table

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I'm afraid the tons of questions that are about alignment of a cell in a table don't solve my issue. The problem is that the cell I want to center is a `multirow` cell. Using a `\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{text}` (as suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/47677/77895)) inside a `multirow` seem not to work.

My MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow,multicol}

\begin{document}  

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{c l c c c}
\hline 
\multirow{2}{*}{Text}  & \multirow{2}{*}{Text to center} & 1234 & 345 & 543 \\
    & & (Four-digit) & (Three-digit) & (Four-digit) \\
\hline \hline
\multirow{3}{*}{Yes} & Managers, and senior officials & 1 & 2 & 1 \\
 & Professional occupations & 2 & 2 & 2 \\
 & Associate professional occupations & 3 & 3 & 3 \\
\hline
\multirow{3}{*}{No} & Personal service occupations & 5 & 6 & 8 \\   
 & Agricultural, fishery and related & 9 & 9 & 9 \\
 & Health service occupations & 8 & 6 & 6 \\
\hline
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Note**: I want to center because I want the rest of the column to be left-aligned.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use  the `makecell`package for that. It allows for line breaks in cells, and a common formatting. By default, the contents of a `\makecell` command is centred both vertically and horizontally (but this may be changed with an optional argument) whatever the alignment in the column. Additionally, you have one less row.

I took the opportunity to use the rules of `booktabs`, which adds some vertical padding around them.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow,multicol, makecell, booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \begin{tabular}{c l c c c}
    \toprule
    {Text} & \makecell{Text to center} & \makecell{1234 & & \\ Four-digit} & \makecell{345\\Three-digit }& \makecell{543\\Four-digit }\\
    \cmidrule{1-5}\morecmidrules \cmidrule{1-5}
    \multirow{3}{*}{Yes} & Managers, and senior officials & 1 & 2 & 1 \\
                         & Professional occupations & 2 & 2 & 2 \\
                         & Associate professional occupations & 3 & 3 & 3 \\
    \cmidrule(lr){1-5}
    \multirow{3}{*}{No} & Personal service occupations & 5 & 6 & 8 \\
                         & Agricultural, fishery and related & 9 & 9 & 9 \\
                         & Health service occupations & 8 & 6 & 6 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Just add an `\hfil` and `\hfill` about the item in question.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow,multicol}

\begin{document}  

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{c l c c c}
\hline 
\multirow{2}{*}{Text}  & \hfil\multirow{2}{*}{Text to center}\hfill & 1234 & 345 & 543 \\
    & & (Four-digit) & (Three-digit) & (Four-digit) \\
\hline \hline
\multirow{3}{*}{Yes} & Managers, and senior officials & 1 & 2 & 1 \\
 & Professional occupations & 2 & 2 & 2 \\
 & Associate professional occupations & 3 & 3 & 3 \\
\hline
\multirow{3}{*}{No} & Personal service occupations & 5 & 6 & 8 \\   
 & Agricultural, fishery and related & 9 & 9 & 9 \\
 & Health service occupations & 8 & 6 & 6 \\
\hline
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Just add a `multicolumn`-environment around your `multirow`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow,multicol}

\begin{document}  

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{c l c c c}
\hline 
\multirow{2}{*}{Text}  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{2}{*}{ Text to center}} & 1234 & 345 & 543 \\
    & & (Four-digit) & (Three-digit) & (Four-digit) \\
\hline \hline
\multirow{3}{*}{Yes} & Managers, and senior officials & 1 & 2 & 1 \\
 & Professional occupations & 2 & 2 & 2 \\
 & Associate professional occupations & 3 & 3 & 3 \\
\hline
\multirow{3}{*}{No} & Personal service occupations & 5 & 6 & 8 \\   
 & Agricultural, fishery and related & 9 & 9 & 9 \\
 & Health service occupations & 8 & 6 & 6 \\
\hline
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}  

\begin{table}
\begin{NiceTabular}{c l c c c}
\hline 
\Block{2-1}{Text}  & \Block[c]{2-1}{Text to center} & 1234 & 345 & 543 \\
    & & (Four-digit) & (Three-digit) & (Four-digit) \\
\hline \hline
\Block{3-1}{Yes} & Managers, and senior officials & 1 & 2 & 1 \\
 & Professional occupations & 2 & 2 & 2 \\
 & Associate professional occupations & 3 & 3 & 3 \\
\hline
\Block{3-1}{No} & Personal service occupations & 5 & 6 & 8 \\   
 & Agricultural, fishery and related & 9 & 9 & 9 \\
 & Health service occupations & 8 & 6 & 6 \\
\hline
\end{NiceTabular} 
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]