# Center first line of a table

Tags: tables

I'm working with

```
\begin{tabular}{lll}
\textbf{text} & \textbf{text} & \textbf{text}\\
&&\\
.
.
.
&&\\
\end{tabular}
```

Since `lll` puts everything at the left. What's the way to center the words of the first line of the table and the rest lines have the `lll` align?

---

I'm using

```
\begin{tabular}{lll}
\multicolumn{3}{c}\textbf{text} & \textbf{text} &\textbf{text}\\
&&\\
&&\\
\end{tabular}
```

But it's nor working.

Comment: \multicolumn{3}{c}{your text} \\

Comment: If you want to center each of the 3 Texts, then you can do Christians approach just with `{1}` in every cell, see also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33486/aligning-inside-tabular-environment-specific-cell

Comment: I tried `\multicolumn{3}{c}{your text}` but it gave me an error. Also I tried putting `{1}` on each cell but it gave me a bad result.

Comment: Use `\hfil\textbf{text}` instead `\textbf{text}`.

Comment: See my edited answer please.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was pretty sure that this is a duplicate question, but any other question I found was way more complicated.  In any case, the correct way to use `\multicolumn` is:

```
\begin{tabular}{lll}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{text}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{text}} &\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{text}}\\
a&b&c\\
12346543432&1253156&lalala\\
\end{tabular}
```

[image: the final table]

Note:

1. The first argument tells how many cells you want to combine together.  Here, you just want to change a single cell by itself and not combine it with any neighbouring cell.
2. The second argument specifies the format of the cell (here: 'c'entered).
3. The third argument (!) is the contents of the cell.  Thus, the contents of the cell as to be between `{` and `}`.

Answer (score 6):

The `thead` command, from `makecell`, allows for a common formatting of its argument, line breaks and is by default vertically and horizontally centred.

Demo of usage:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array, makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{lll}
  \thead{text1\\text2} & \thead{text} &\thead{text}\\
  Blah blah & Blah blah & Blah blah \\
  Blah & Blah & Blah \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]