# Table: Align single cell without using multicolumn

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, multicolumn

I would like to center the content of certain cells (actually the whole first row) of my table, while the rest of the table is left-aligned.

It works with `multicolumn`, but when using `multicolumn` it does not break the content of the cell and puts all the text in one line.

I wonder if there is not a simple command, such as {`\centering`} (which I tried and doesn't work), without the "detour" via multicolumn?

```
\begin{table}[h] 
    \centering
    \label{example}
    \noindent\begin{tabular}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{3cm}|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{3cm}|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{3cm}|}\hline 
     here I want centering and line breaking  &here too  &here too \\ \hline
     the rest aligned on the left & left1 & left2\\ \hline
     3 & 4 & 5 \\ \hline
     \end{tabular}
     \end{table}
```

Comment: See if this could help you, for example: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/280006/101651. Otherwise, please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: if the column is a p column `\centering` will work, if it was an `l` column then line breaking is disabled anyway and using `\multicolumn{1}{c}` does not change that, so with no example code it is very hard to understand your question.

Comment: You wrote, "but when using multicolumn it does not break the content of the cell and puts all the text in one line". That's not necessarily true. Please tell us how the columns are defined at present.

Comment: I tried using: \multicolumn{1}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{3cm}}{text}, but I do not understand what is wrong with it?

Comment: @Fraenzine - There shouldn't be any issue with the command you list, except that you may want to have a vertical bar at the right-hand edge of the cell -- in which case you should write `\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{3cm}|}{text}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't understand your apparent aversion to using `\multicolumn` to override the default column type on a cell-by-cell basis.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array} % for "\newcolumntype" directive
%% Argument of 'M' and 'N' col. types: usable col. width, in cm
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{#1cm}}
\newcolumntype{N}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1cm}}
%% Two convenient shortcut macros
\newcommand{\mC}[2]{\multicolumn{1}{ N{#1}|}{#2}}
\newcommand{\mD}[2]{\multicolumn{1}{|N{#1}|}{#2}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h] 
\centering
\caption{An example}
    \label{tab:example}
    \begin{tabular}{|M{3}|M{2.5}|M{3.5}|}
     \hline 
       \mD{3}{here I want centering and line breaking} 
     & \mC{2.5}{here too} 
     & \mC{3.5}{here too} \\
     \hline
     the rest aligned on the left, with line breaking 
     & left1 & left2\\ 
     \hline
     3.0 & 2.5 & 3.5 \\ 
     \hline
     \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This looks good, thank you! Can you please explain me how you managed to make it break the line? Is it the \arraybackslash command that you use for defining the columntype?  Another question, what is the \mD or \mC doing? I am relatively new to Latex, so I am a little confused.

Comment: @Fraenzine - The use of the `m` column type in the `\newcolumntype` definitions of `N` and `M` allows line breaks. The `\arraybackslash` directive is there purely to bypass a deep-seated LaTeX issue which would otherwise affect the final (i.e, right-hand-most) column in a table. The macros `\mC` and `\mD`, which both take two arguments, are handy shortcuts: They save you from the tedium of having to write `\multicolumn{1}{ N{<some number>cm}|}{<some text>}` and `\multicolumn{1}{ |N{<some number>cm}|}{<some text>}`, respectively. Isn't it easier to write, say, `\mC{<some number>}{<some text>}`?

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can use the `\Centering`, `\RaggedLeft` and`\RaggedRight` commands from the package `ragged2e`. Among other things, these commands are modified so that they preserve the present meaning of `\\` (which is different if you're inside a `tabular` environment), unlike their basic LaTeX equivalents `\centering`, `\raggedleft`, `\raggedright`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h] 
    \centering
    \label{example}
    \noindent
    \begin{tabular}{|>{\RaggedRight}m{3cm}|>{\RaggedRight}m{3cm}|>{\RaggedRight}m{3cm}|}
        \hline 
        \Centering here I want centering and line breaking  & \Centering here too  & \Centering here too \\ \hline
        the rest aligned on the left & left1 & left2\\ \hline
        3 & 4 & 5 \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```