# Centering of the first row under multicolum headings in tables

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, multicolumn

I want to center the row under the multicolumn heading. In the table below I want to center the **M=16** and **M=32** without disturbing the layout of content in the figure below. The Red marker showing content required to be centered only.

```
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\caption{Values of Dispersion Constant ($R$)}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Algorithm}} & \multicolumn{2}{ c|}{{\boldmath\textbf{Dispersion Constant ($R$)}}}\\
\hline
& \textbf{\centering M=16} & \textbf{\centering M=32}\\ \hline 
SCA & R\textsubscript{SCA} = 123 & R\textsubscript{SCA} = 123 \\\hline
\end{table}
MCMA & R\textsubscript{R}=2.55 and R\textsubscript{I}=2.55  & R\textsubscript{R}=2.55 and R\textsubscript{I}=2.55\\
\hline 
\multirow{2}*{DD-MCMA} & R\textsubscript{R1} = 123 and R\textsubscript{R2} = 123 & R\textsubscript{R1} = 123 and R\textsubscript{R2} = 123 \\
& R\textsubscript{R1} = 123 and R\textsubscript{R2} = 123 & R\textsubscript{R1} = 123 and R\textsubscript{R2} = 123 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: You asked the same question yesterday

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use `\multicolumn{1}{c|}{...}` for the cell you want to center.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\caption{Values of Dispersion Constant ($R$)}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Algorithm}} & \multicolumn{2}{ c|}{{\boldmath\textbf{Dispersion Constant ($R$)}}}\\
\hline
& \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{M=16}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{M=32}}\\ \hline 
SCA & R\textsubscript{SCA} = 123 & R\textsubscript{SCA} = 123 \\\hline
MCMA & R\textsubscript{R}=2.55 and R\textsubscript{I}=2.55  & R\textsubscript{R}=2.55 and R\textsubscript{I}=2.55\\
\hline 
\multirow{2}*{DD-MCMA} & R\textsubscript{R1} = 123 and R\textsubscript{R2} = 123 & R\textsubscript{R1} = 123 and R\textsubscript{R2} = 123 \\
& R\textsubscript{R1} = 123 and R\textsubscript{R2} = 123 & R\textsubscript{R1} = 123 and R\textsubscript{R2} = 123 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Do u know how I can fully justify the content of above given content in last row?  Just like u did it above.

Comment: I mean fully justified content in tables as the contents are left justified here as `\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}`. e.g RSCA,RR1 and RR2 etc

Comment: Is the `p{...}` works for horizontal line alignment? I want text in table to be justified horizontally.

Comment: Ok. I submitted the new question
[link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/440000/fully-justified-contents-in-tables)

Comment: Please check out the question of the op from yesterday. Duplicate?

Comment: Certainly a dupe on tex.sx available

Comment: @Johannes_B It's certainly a dupe. Since the OP used the `\multicolumn` with one column in his code snipped, I presume he didn't understand it.

Comment: Close as dupe of the question from yesterday?

Comment: Or of this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33486/aligning-inside-tabular-environment-specific-cell