# Fully Justified Contents in Tables

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I need to fully justified the contents of table such as RSCA ,RR1 ,RR2 etc values. Is there any way to provide values in a table that is **fully justified** horizontally not the **Left Aligned** such as we provided `\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}` which left aligned the content.

The code is shown below:

```
\def\arraystretch{1.3}%
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\caption{Values of Dispersion Constant ($R$)}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Algorithm}} & \multicolumn{2}{ c|}{{\boldmath\textbf{Dispersion Constant ($R$)}}}\\
\hline
& \multicolumn{1}{ c|}{\textbf{M=16}} & \multicolumn{1}{ c|}{\textbf{M=32}}\\ \hline 
SCA & R\textsubscript{SCA} = 123 & R\textsubscript{SCA} = 123 \\\hline
\justifying
MCMA & R\textsubscript{R} = 2.55 and R\textsubscript{I} = 2.55  & R\textsubscript{R} = 2.55 and R\textsubscript{I} = 2.55\\
\hline 
\multirow{2}*{DD-MCMA} & R\textsubscript{R1} = 0.75 and R\textsubscript{R2} = 2.55 & R\textsubscript{R1} = 0.75 and R\textsubscript{R2} = 2.55 \\
& R\textsubscript{I1} = 0.75 and R\textsubscript{I2} = 2.55 & R\textsubscript{I1} = 0.75 and R\textsubscript{I2} = 2.55 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

I want to make the this part of code to appear Justified Aligned Horizontally

```
SCA & R\textsubscript{SCA} = 123 & R\textsubscript{SCA} = 123 \\\hline
\justifying
MCMA & R\textsubscript{R} = 2.55 and R\textsubscript{I} = 2.55  & 
R\textsubscript{R} = 2.55 and R\textsubscript{I} = 2.55\\
\hline 
\multirow{2}*{DD-MCMA} & R\textsubscript{R1} = 0.75 and R\textsubscript{R2} 
= 2.55 & R\textsubscript{R1} = 0.75 and R\textsubscript{R2} = 2.55 \\
& R\textsubscript{I1} = 0.75 and R\textsubscript{I2} = 2.55 & 
R\textsubscript{I1} = 0.75 and R\textsubscript{I2} = 2.55 \\
\hline
```

Comment: By default the `p` type column is justified, but with a fixed width you have to specify. Where does the `\justifying` macro originate from?

Comment: @skillmon ragged2e

Comment: Shall the contents be stretched? How do you imagine this justification being made for the small equation `R\textsubscript{SCA} = 123` compared to the longer equations in the other rows? And why do you insert those equations in text mode not in maths mode?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 5):

*Edit 1 (reply to the comment):*

Explanation of the column types (code after `tabular`):

1. with `>{...}` you can tell LaTeX to do something *before* writing the cell content, with `<{...}` something *after*; you need `array` package for these options
2. with `S[table-format=1.2]` you tell LaTeX you have numbers with 1 integer and 2 decimal to be aligned at the decimal point (package `siunitx` is needed)
3. with `@{something}` you can insert `something` instead of the inter-column space (`array` package)
4. with `!{something}` you can insert `something` instead of the `|` (always see `array` package).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[h]
        \centering\footnotesize
        \caption{Values of Dispersion Constant ($R$)}
        \begin{tabular}{
                |l|
                >{$}l<{$}@{${}={}$}S[table-format=1.2]
                !{and}
                >{$}l<{$}@{${}={}$}S[table-format=1.2]|
                >{$}l<{$}@{${}={}$}S[table-format=1.2]
                !{and}
                >{$}l<{$}@{${}={}$}S[table-format=1.2]|
            }
            \hline
            \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Algorithm}} & \multicolumn{8}{ c|}{{\boldmath\textbf{Dispersion Constant ($R$)}}}\\
            \hline
            & \multicolumn{4}{ c|}{\boldmath $M=16$} & \multicolumn{4}{ c|}{\boldmath $M=32$}\\ \hline 
            SCA & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{$R_{\text{SCA}}=123$} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{$R_{\text{SCA}}=123$} \\\hline
            MCMA & R_{\text{R}} & 2.55 & R_{\text{I}} & 2.55  & R_{\text{R}} & 2.55 & R_{\text{I}} & 2.55\\
            \hline 
            DD-MCMA & R_\text{{R1}} & 0.75 & R_{\text{R2}} & 2.55 & R_{\text{R1}} & 0.75 & R_{\text{R2}} & 2.55 \\
            & R_{\text{I1}} & 0.75 & R_{\text{I2}} & 2.55 & R_{\text{I1}} & 0.75 & R_{\text{I2}} & 2.55 \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

*Edit 2 (this is what the OP want, not what I like):*

If you want the Word alignment, use `\hfill`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
\def\arraystretch{1.3}%
\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \caption{Values of Dispersion Constant ($R$)}
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
        \hline
        \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Algorithm}} & \multicolumn{2}{ c|}{{\boldmath\textbf{Dispersion Constant ($R$)}}}\\
        \hline
        & \multicolumn{1}{ c|}{\textbf{M=16}} & \multicolumn{1}{ c|}{\textbf{M=32}}\\ \hline 
        SCA & R\textsubscript{SCA} \hfill = \hfill 123 & R\textsubscript{SCA} \hfill = \hfill 123 \\\hline
        MCMA & R\textsubscript{R} \hfill = \hfill 2.55 \hfill and R\textsubscript{I} \hfill = \hfill 2.55  & R\textsubscript{R} \hfill = 2.55 \hfill and \hfill R\textsubscript{I} \hfill = \hfill 2.55\\
        \hline 
        \multirow{2}*{DD-MCMA} & R\textsubscript{R1} \hfill = \hfill 0.75 \hfill and \hfill R\textsubscript{R2} \hfill = \hfill 2.55 & R\textsubscript{R1} \hfill = \hfill 0.75 \hfill and \hfill R\textsubscript{R2} \hfill = \hfill 2.55 \\
        & R\textsubscript{I1} \hfill = \hfill 0.75 \hfill and \hfill R\textsubscript{I2} \hfill = \hfill 2.55 & R\textsubscript{I1} \hfill = 0.75 \hfill and \hfill R\textsubscript{I2} \hfill = \hfill 2.55 \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Its giving error **! Package array Error: Illegal pream-token (S): `c' used.**

Comment: I cannot understand the code after `\begin{tabular}`

Comment: I just want my contents in table cell to be justified just as MS word justifies the text.

Comment: @FaizanZaheer Look at _Edit 1_ and _Edit 2_.

Comment: @FaizanZaheer For column type `S` you should load `siunitx` package.