# How to lnsert Centered Vertical Dots in a Table with Multiply lmages to Express Omit

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

Sorry for the bother to everyone here! I have a question about vertical dots, generally, I'm now using `\vdot` in a table to express omit, but I want them to be centralized to express omit, the current codes are shown below:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb} % Add
\usepackage{bbding} % Add
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\def\tabularxcolumn#1{m{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}[htbp]
    \caption{Text.}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ l Sl X }
    \toprule
        Iterations & Samples & Comments \\
    \midrule
        0     & \includegraphics[width=.6\textwidth,valign=M]{000000.png} & Text is always being here\\
        32    & \includegraphics[width=.6\textwidth,valign=M]{000000.png} & Text \\ 
        64    & \includegraphics[width=.6\textwidth,valign=M]{000000.png} & Text \\
        128   & \includegraphics[width=.6\textwidth,valign=M]{000000.png} & Text \\
        192   & \includegraphics[width=.6\textwidth,valign=M]{000000.png} & Text \\
        \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
        3200  & \includegraphics[width=.6\textwidth,valign=M]{000000.png} & Text \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
    \label{tab4}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

Please keep the gap between different rows and let all others align left, except nine dots. Thanks to everyone in advance!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please expand your code to a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: Why did you put `\includegraphics` inside math mode?

Comment: @dexteritas Sorry, I had modified the error and made it a MEW.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Adaptations

- use `example-image` for the [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)

  - added option `height=20mm` only for that example image
- use `\multicolumn{1}{c}{\vdots}` to align single cell centered (see [Aligning inside tabular environment, specific cell](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33486/123129))
- numbers should be right aligned in tables (better style)

#### Code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb} % Add
\usepackage{bbding} % Add
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\def\tabularxcolumn#1{m{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}[htbp]
    \caption{Text.}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ r Sl X }
    \toprule
        Iterations & Samples & Comments \\
    \midrule
        0     & \includegraphics[width=.6\textwidth, height=20mm, valign=M]{example-image} & Text is always being here\\
        32    & \includegraphics[width=.6\textwidth, height=20mm, valign=M]{example-image} & Text \\ 
        64    & \includegraphics[width=.6\textwidth, height=20mm, valign=M]{example-image} & Text \\
        128   & \includegraphics[width=.6\textwidth, height=20mm, valign=M]{example-image} & Text \\
        192   & \includegraphics[width=.6\textwidth, height=20mm, valign=M]{example-image} & Text \\
        \vdots & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\vdots} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\vdots} \\
        3200  & \includegraphics[width=.6\textwidth, height=20mm, valign=M]{example-image} & Text \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
    \label{tab4}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

#### Result

[image]

Comment: Thanks! It works perfectly!